# Prove $|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}|\geq|e^{i\theta_1/2}-e^{i\theta_2/2}|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove $|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}|\geq|e^{i\theta_1/2}-e^{i\theta_2/2}|$
>   where $ \theta_1, \theta_2 \in (0,\pi]$.

Even though geometrically it is an obvious fact, somehow I couldn't prove it elegant way (it's really frustrating), and I'm sure some of you guys know how to prove it in two or three lines.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: sorry $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in (0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : 
$\bigg|
\frac
{e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}}
{e^{\frac{i\theta_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{i\theta_2}{2}}}\bigg|=
\bigg|e^{\frac{i\theta_1}{2}}+e^{\frac{i\theta_2}{2}}\bigg|=\bigg|e^{i\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{4}}+e^{i\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{4}}\bigg|=2|\cos(\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{4})|$.

Comment: yeah ok. I rather thought about some clever usage of triangle inequality, taking factors out etc. But thank you

Comment: And here you have  something that is dependent on $z:=y-x \in (-2\pi,2\pi]$ so there are many cases I think

Comment: @Kacper please see my updated version

Comment: That's very clever I love it

Comment: no in fact i don't love it but thanks

Comment: Wait but from what you wrote above it follows that the claim is not true, is it?

Comment: By the way, did you notice there was a typo, I just corrected it.

Comment: because $ 2|cos(\frac{\theta_2−\theta_1}{4})|\geq1$ is not always true is it?

Comment: The claim is indeed false : consider $\theta_1=0,\theta_2$ strictly between $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: No but it has to work in the range $(0,\pi]$ because $|e^{\frac{i\theta_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{i\theta_2}{2}}|=|e^{\frac{i\theta_1}{2}}||e^{\frac{i\theta_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{i\theta_2}{2}}|=|e^\{i\theta_1}-e^{\frac{i\theta_2}{2}}$ and this is gepmetrically simply triangle inequality

Answer (score 0):

When $\theta_1\space\wedge\space\theta_2\in\mathbb{R}$:

1. $$e^{\theta_1i}-e^{\theta_2i}=\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin\left(\theta_1\right)i-\left(\cos\left(\theta_2\right)+\sin\left(\theta_2\right)i\right)=$$
   $$\cos\left(\theta_1\right)-\cos\left(\theta_2\right)+\left(\sin\left(\theta_1\right)-\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\right)i$$
2. $$e^{\frac{\theta_1i}{2}}-e^{\frac{\theta_2i}{2}}=\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)i-\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)i\right)=$$
   $$\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)+\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)\right)i$$

So:

1. $$\left|e^{\theta_1i}-e^{\theta_2i}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\cos\left(\theta_1\right)-\cos\left(\theta_2\right)\right)^2+\left(\sin\left(\theta_1\right)-\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\right)^2}=\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos\left(\theta_1-\theta_2\right)\right)}$$
2. $$\left|e^{\frac{\theta_1i}{2}}-e^{\frac{\theta_2i}{2}}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)\right)^2+\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)\right)^2}=$$
   $$2\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: ok, but for me is totally not obvious why $(1.)\geq(2.)$

Comment: Use trigoniometric identitys and try to prove it

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time